# Outlook add-on error: "Requested registry access is not allowed"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, vsto

I found this code on Stackoverflow and used it in a Outlook 2010 add-in and for some reason I still get

> "Requested registry access is not allowed."

I am trying to change a value in a DWORD key.

```
var admin = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            RegistryKey LocalMachine = Registry.LocalMachine;
            RegistryKey rk = LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(sSubKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.ChangePermissions | RegistryRights.ReadKey);//Get the registry key desired with ChangePermissions Rights.
           if (rk == null)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No RegKey");
            }
            RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
            rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(admin, RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));//Create access rule giving full control to the Administrator user.
            rk.SetAccessControl(rs); //Apply the new access rule to this Registry Key.
            rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(sKSubKey, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl); // Opens the key again with full control.
            rs.SetOwner(new NTAccount(admin));// Set the securitys owner to be Administrator
            rk.SetAccessControl(rs);// Set the key with 

            Registry.SetValue(sSubKey, sKey, sValue, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the HKLM hive only if your code is running as a local admin and UAC is either off or your app had been grated elevated privileges.

Comment: I am local admin. Is there a way to run and outlook add-on with admin privileges without start outlook as "run as administrator"?

Comment: No, the privileges are granted on the per-process basis, so your addin will use outlook.exe process privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to the HKLM hive in newer versions of Windows (starting from Vista) unless you have administrative privileges. Take a look at the similar threads for more information:

- [Requested registry access is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562350/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed)
- [Impersonation in .NET in Windows 7 (Requested registry access is not allowed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573192/impersonation-in-net-in-windows-7-requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windows Vista. The same limitation applied back in the Windows NT 3.51 days.